# C++ - See if an hWnd window is responding or not?

Tags: c++

I'm making an application to change some information around in another window. 
The problem is, Sometimes it causes the window to "Not Respond."

So my question is, Using C++, How do I check to see if the window is still running or not?

I'm using this to look at my window:

```
HWND hWnds = FindWindow(0, WindowName);

 if (hWnds <= 0) {
      gameFound = false;
 } else {
        DWORD pId;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnds, &pId);
        hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pId);

        if (!hProc) {
               std::cout << "Failed.";
        } else {
               std::cout << "Window Found!";
```

Comment: Don't do that, instead try to find out *why* your program stops responding. One way is through running in a debugger, another is by having copious amount of logging.

Answer (score 0):

Windows periodically sends out an event that asks if the program is alive, then it waits for it to respond. And if it doesn't respond within a certain amount of time it assumes it has crashed and says "not responding". So what you need to do is handle the window events.